# How to Extend/Inherit Angular 4 component, but only behavior, keeping the template

Tags: angular, inheritance, web-component

I have a little question about extend the component behavior, I need add some properties but the template must remain the same. 
By example:
   I want to extend MdToggleButton keeping the original template and only adding support for some properties and some behavior.

Is it possible in Angular 4?

Some suggestion?

Thanks..

Comment: Yes. You want to write an attribute directive. https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives

Comment: Sounds good, but I need to add several properties and manage them within the component, the directive seems to me that it is more about manipulating the DOM.